# Click function .slideToggle After open

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
// Toggle
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('.extra').slideToggle();
});

.extra {
    display: none;
}

 #toggle {
 cursor:pointer;
 width:100%;
 display:block;
 text-align: center;
 padding:10px 0;
 color:#777;

}
```

using font awesome fa fa-chevron-down im trying to make it so once the slideToggle has been opened it changes to fa fa-chevron-down

im pretty sure this is very simple but i cant seem to find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('.extra').slideToggle(400, function(){
    $("#toggle .additionalClassToTheIcon").toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down");
  });
});
```

Where **400** is the duration of the animation, you can change it to whatever you want. **additionalClassToTheIcon** is the additional class to the icon so you can always identify it.

Also check this documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: $('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('.extra').slideToggle(400, function(){
    $("#toggle.fa").removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
  });
});

Comment: this worked for me but once opened when i close it again the arrow stays pointing up

Comment: Check my last edit, forgot to handle the close action

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#toggle .iconClassHere").hasClass("fa-chevron-down")) {
    $("#toggle .iconClassHere").removeClass("fa-chevron-down");
    $("#toggle .iconClassHere").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
}else {
    $("#toggle .iconClassHere").removeClass("fa-chevron-up");
    $("#toggle .iconClassHere").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
}
```